# How do I add a boilerplate comment or license to the top of a JavaScript file compiled using the Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am using the Asset Pipeline to build some JavaScript that will be handed over to a number of third party developers. I want to place a warning comment at the top of the generated (and possibly obfuscated) output file but it's not clear how to achieve this with the sprockets / coffeescript combo.

```
# This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
# Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
# be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
# It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
# the compiled file.
###
  The following code was compiled from source by MF. 
  Please do not edit this JavaScript directly.  
####
#= require util/extensions
#= require util/date_manipulation
#= require util/format
#= require points_data
#= require graphics/canvas_graphics
#= require graphics/explorer_canvas_graphics
#= require renderer
```

I get the following result with this:

```
(function() {
  /*
    The following code was compiled from source by MF. 
    Please do not edit this JavaScript directly.  
  */
}).call(this);
```

What I want is this (or something close):

```
/*
    The following code was compiled from source by MF. 
    Please do not edit this JavaScript directly.  
  */
(function() {
  // ******** my compiled code from all those required files! *******
}).call(this);
```

How'm'I gonna get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to add a comment to the file after compilation.

The default compressor for Rails - Uglifier - has a :copyright option for keeping the first comment lines of files, so you could possibly use that to leave the comment (and all other copyrights) in.

`config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(:copyright => true)`

Comment: I obviously don't want any manual steps after compilation - so where would I hook in to add this comment?

Comment: If you are precompiling locally, you'll need to put that in application.rb. I would put your special comment in its own file and include that first in the manifest. Use /* comment syntax */ in the file.

Comment: The copyright flag is true by default.  Something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The toolset from JetBrains has a 'Copyright' plugin
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/88-copyright/

It allows injecting your copyright/headers to your source files.
I've tried it for IntelliJ Idea and RubyMine and it works for me.

This plugin might be applied to the whole project, directory or recently changed files.